# For and If in R data programming

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I want to evaluate the distance between non-zero data. So if i have 50 data, and only the first and last data is non-zero, thus i want the result to be 49.

For example, my data is:

```
1. 0
2. 0
3. 5
4. 6
5. 0
6. 1
7. 0
```

Based on my data above, i want to get 4 variables:

```
v0 = 3 (because the distance between 0th to 3rd data is 3 jumps)
v1 = 1 (because the distance between 3rd to 4th data is 1 jump)
v2 = 2 (because the distance between 4rd to 6th data is 2 jump)
v3 = 1 (because the distance between 6rd to 7th data is 1 jump)
```

This is my code:

```
data=c(0,0,5,6,0,1,0)

t=1
for (i in data) {
  if (i == 0) {
    t[i]=t+1
  }
  else {
    t[i]=1
  }
}

t
```

The result is:

```
[1]  1 NA NA NA  1  1
```

Could you help me in figuring out this problem? I also hope that the code is using some kind of loop, so that it can be applied to any other data.

Comment: I cannot understand why v0 is jump from 0th to 3rd?

Comment: In your code you are using i to set the value of t[i]. But i assumes all values in your vector data (and not the values from 1 to the length of the vector data. So this means only the values t[0], t[1], t[5], and t[6] will be assigned a value and the rest will be undefined (NA). So your code is working as expected. I am uncertain what you are exactly trying to get as an output though, so I can't help there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is not clear from the question but if `x` is the input we assume that:

- the input is non-negative
- the first element in output is the position of the first +ve element in `x`
- subsequent elements of output are distances between successive +ve elements of `x`
- if that results in a vector whose sum is less than `length(x)` append the remainder

To do that determine the positions of the positive elements of `c(1, x)`, calculate the differences between successive elements in that reduced vector using `diff` and then if they don't sum to `length(x)` append the remainder.

```
dists <- function(x) {
  d <- diff(which(c(1, x) > 0))
  if (sum(d) < length(x)) c(d, length(x) - sum(d)) else d
}

# distance to 5 is 3 and then to 6 is 1 and then to 1 is 2 and 1 is left
x1 <- c(0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 1, 0)
dists(x1)
## [1] 3 1 2 1

# distance to first 1 is 1 and from that to second 1 is 3
x2 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)
dists(x2)
## [1] 1 3
```

Here it is redone using a loop:

```
dists2 <- function(x) {
  pos <- 0
  out <- numeric(0)
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i]) {
      out <- c(out, i - pos)
      pos <- i
    }
  }
  if (sum(out) < length(x)) out <- c(out, length(x) - sum(out))
  out
}

dists2(x1)
## [1] 3 1 2 1

dists2(x2)
## [1] 1 3
```

### Updates

Simplification based on comments below answer.  Added loop approach.

Comment: As good as answer as any. Minor quibble: "nonzero" *might* be "less than zero" in some contexts. Also, your `d` can be defined more simply as `diff(which(c(1,x) != 0))`.

Comment: Based on the examples in the question that input is non-negative. Have added your simplification using `which`.